# Tridion profiling/tracking

Tags: tridion

We're looking at a requirement to track a users journey through a Tridion-managed website, then be able identify this user as a "prospect" based on this behaviour and then trigger an email to this user if they dont return after X number of days.

Can SmartTarget "track" a user journey between pages out-the-box or would it require some sort of custom Ambient Data Framework cartridge?

The older P&P module did this kind of tracking but I don't recall there being away to use that data in an Outbound Email triggered mail - so send an email when a tracking count for user got above a certain figure?

Cheers

Comment: That's where the Audience Manager Segments come into play: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_E51C198E2DAA41CAB2ECF876570A2AF4

Comment: Thansk Nuno, but not sure how segments would help with tracking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartTarget nor P&P is not going to help you here.

Because your requirement is sending an email you need you user to be an audience manager user,

you could do the tracking in ADF and then have that update an extended detail for the user when the threshold is reached,
Create a Dynamic Distribution list on the ext. detail en create a triggered mailing on that list

To do this "out of the box" is a long standing wish of mine, might be possible in the future :)